# Technically, is 'three bright' valid?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

In conversation, we usually use 'three degrees bright/brighter,' but I doubt three bright/brighter can be the case.

Comment: What would it mean? Have you seen the expression somewhere?

Comment: @Jack O'Flaherty I mean the adjective meaning being bright to three degrees.

Comment: Who uses three degrees bright/brighter' in conversation? I have never heard it.

Comment: @Michael Harvey I'm confused with 'hot' that's so funny LOL

Comment: @agreement to expand on Jack O'flaherty's question: Is this an expression you "usually use" in English or your native language?

Comment: @sharur yes 3도만큼 밝다 3도만큼 뜨겁다

Comment: If you have a dimmer controller, you might be able to make the light 3 steps brighter.

Comment: @Peter I love you

Comment: The steps refer to steps on the controller, they don't actually refer to brightness. Note too, some controllers are continuous and don't have steps. You would need to describe the movement of the controller some other way.

Comment: @peter what about three buttons brighter

Comment: Only if the controller is a row of buttons. There are sliders and knobs with numbers next to them so you might have 3 numbers brighter. Steps is probably the most general.

Comment: @Peter Thank you very much

Comment: We do say _three degrees warmer_ of course since we measure temperature in degrees but none of the SI units for light is measured in degrees.

Comment: This is wasting everybody's time.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Talking of 3 brighter makes little sense, and 3 degrees brighter is also hard to understand. If you have a brightness controller of some kind you might be able to talk about 3 steps brighter. In such expressions you are describing what to do with the controller. Other possibilities are 3 notches brighter, 3 numbers brighter, etc.